# Is there any way to change Snap download mirror?

Tags: apt, snap

I'm using ubuntu 19.04 with Ubuntu Store installed.

I usually download and install snaps using `snap` command but I'm facing very low download speed issue with that. While packages from ubuntu repositories get downloaded at some reliable speed.

I really want a way to change snap download mirror(if it support). Please guide me about that if there is any way.